# Переполнение буфера на C

Tags: linux, c, overflow, buffer

Не могу понять как решать задание.
Имеется программа (исходный код которой приводится ниже,
компилировать с ключами: -fno-stack-protector -no-pie). Вам необходимо
произвести анализ программы с помощью отладчика для выяснения длины
массива для ввода пароля и адреса ветки условия проверки корректности
ввода пароля, которая выполняется при условии совпадения паролей.
Ввести пароль (строку символов)таким образом, чтобы перезаписать адрес
возврата на выясненный адрес (есть символы которые нельзя ввести с
клавиатуры, поэтому можно использовать перенаправление ввода(<) при
запуске программы).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int IsPassOk(void);
int main(void)
{
 int PwStatus;
 puts("Enter password:");
 PwStatus = IsPassOk();
 if (PwStatus == 0) {
  printf("Bad password!\n");
 exit(1);
 } else {
  printf("Access granted!\n"); // Строка для которой нужно выяснить адрес
 }
 return 0;
}

int IsPassOk(void)
{
 char Pass[12];
 gets(Pass);
 return 0 == strcmp(Pass, "test");
}
```

Comment: Для начала прочтите про ASLR (искать в гугле), например, [тут](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318315/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization). Затем, вам надо получить ассемблерный листинг (флаг `-S` для gcc) и найти в нем -- 1) смещение `else { printf ...` от main и 2) смещение извлекаемого адреса возврата из IsPassOk от начала поля Pass[] (это даст вам длину строки (остается надеяться, что `\n` не окажется среди символов, формирующих значение адреса -)), которая изменит адрес). М.б. тут проще испльзовать gdb и немного полазить им по памяти, начиная с `Pass`